# Is there a way to create a socket cluster of 64-bit instances?

Tags: r

I am working on an application the uses [Snowfall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html) to create a socket cluster. The master instance seems to be 64-bit but the slave instances are 32-bit. How do I get Snow/Snowfall to use 64-bit slave instances instead?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select the slave instances by providing hostnames or IP addresses then it is up to you provide 64-bit instances rather than 32-bit instances.

Comment: The cluster is on a 64-bit machine, the problem i'm having is that snow/snowfall instance the 32-bit version of Rscript instead of the 64-bit version